# Check if a number is prime

Tags: scheme, racket

I am writing a small function that checks whether a number is prime. I am trouble converting how I would check it in C++ to scheme. Mainly the **or** operator.

```
if( ( (n % 2) == 0) || (n != 1) )
   ***recursive again***
else
    "Done";


(define prime
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 1) n
        (if (or (= (modulo n 2) 0) (not ( = n 1))) prime(n)
            (display "Done")
            )
        )
    )
  )
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the problem exactly ? error ? unexpected output ?

Comment: I get an error with compiling. Stating that in my second if statement stating bad syntax.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Comment: The function you wrote will not identify primes, even if you fix the syntax. Since you seem to speak C++, my suggestion is to write a working `is_prime(n)` function in C++ first, then once it is working, translate to Scheme.

Comment: You have three branches: `prime`, `(n)`, and `(display "Done")`. Review the Scheme syntax in your book.

Comment: The correct way to call `prime` recursively is `(prime n)`, not `prime(n)`. This is basic Scheme/Lisp syntax -- you obbviously know that since you called `modulo` and `display` correctly.

Comment: But when you recurse, you have to use a different parameter than the original, otherwise you'll just recurse infinitely.

Comment: The basic principle of recursion is that you should call it with an argument that gets you closer to your base case.

Comment: But prime checking isn't really a recursive algorithm. Normally you just loop through all the possible factors, checking if any of them are divisors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple function to recognize prime numbers:

```
(define (prime? n)
  (let loop ((d 2))
    (cond ((< n (* d d)) #t)
          ((zero? (modulo n d)) #f)
          (else (loop (+ d 1))))))
```

You have many misconceptions about Scheme, and also about prime numbers. Talk to your teacher; that's what he's there for.

Comment: Thank you! Yea I am just learning to work with scheme and just the idea of everything must be done recursively is a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

named loops are a advanced tool, if this is for homework I would guess the teacher is looking for something like this, using a local function definition to do the recursion

```
(define (prime? n)
  (define (f n c)
    (cond [(< n (* c c)) #t]
          [(zero? (modulo n c)) #f]
          [else (f n (add1 c))]))
  ;in
  (f n 2))
```